# How to resolve this Exception, thrown from ZeroMQ library?

Tags: android, zeromq

I am using ZeroMQ in android for connecting two devices and I am getting an exception, which is **`org.zeromq.ZMQException: Errno 48 : Address already in use`**

Here is my code:

```
ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(             ZMQ.REP );
                            socket.setLinger(   0 );
                            socket.setSndHWM(   0 );
                            socket.setIPv4Only( false );
                            socket.bind(       "tcp://myIP:port" );

while( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
        byte[] msg = socket.recv( 0 );
        uiThreadHandler.sendMessage( Util.bundledMessage( uiThreadHandler,
                                                          new String( msg )
                                                          )
                                     );
        socket.send( new String( Util.reverseInPlace( msg ) ),
                     0
                     );
}
socket.close();
context.term();
}



ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context( 1 );
ZMQ.Socket   socket =     context.socket(          ZMQ.SUB );
                                  socket.connect( "tcp://myIP:port" );
                                  socket.send(     params[0].getBytes(),
                                                   0
                                                   );
String result = new String(       socket.recv( 0 ) );
                                  socket.close();
context.term();
return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### this is a common state in ZeroMQ. <sup>`.bind()` asks, but O/S can & does reject ...</sup>

Operating system simply rejected to allow the **`.bind()`** method to touch such an `<address>:<port#>`, that the O/S-resource-manager still believed that is not free and available for any re-use at the moment of call.

---

### For this very reason, ZeroMQ documentation advices, that:

> **Error handling**
>   
>   The binding should use standard error mechanism of the language, whether it is error codes, exceptions etc.

So the proper Exception-handling is always left to the user-code. This is designer's role and responsibility to define, what steps and measures are in place for such a case to remedy the overall strategy of what shall happen next.

During prototyping, it is common to fall into a deadlocked or not yet released address:port, so sometimes just a use of external reset, reboot can provide the missing step to make the toys act accordingly, as expected.

+1 for designing your code with preventive measures ... **`ZMQ_LINGER`** being a typical such case. Do this always, automatically. It can just save you hours in debugging.

So, stay tuned and enjoy the powers of [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) with ZeroMQ.

Comment: Why not? Just create an appropriate UI-engine, allowing you to control and redistribute all UI-content, add both the { local + remote }-event-collection + propagation towards a common { local }-UI-controller and you are almost there. Some authentication, some cryptographic protection. So, pretty well doable.

Answer (score 0):

**ZMQ.REP / ZMQ.REQ** will require acting in pairs of *send, recv, send, recv...* if your messaging is unidirectional, consider to use **ZMQ.PULL / ZMQ.PUSH** instead.